# Django: Filtering objects with results of another table?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm having a mental blank on how to do this in Django, hoping you can help.

I have a table of galleries that I am filtering by type:

```
public_galleries = models.Gallery.objects.filter(type = 2).filter(root_gallery__isnull = True)
```

but I also want to see if the gallery doesn't exist in the UserGallery table for a specific user. I have this list of galleries for the user:

```
user_galleries = models.UserGallery.objects.select_related().filter(clientuser=request.user.id).filter(gallery__root_gallery__isnull = True)
```

Note** Just started using Django for a real project, so any improvement on either of those statements are also appreciated.

Edit - The Models:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    """Gallery model"""
    name = models.CharField(u"Gallery name", max_length=120)
    type = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    root_gallery = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True)
    """ Other Fields"""

class UserGallery(models.Model):
    """Model to link Gallery and ClientUser"""
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
    clientuser = models.ForeignKey(ClientUser)
    owner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: It is best to include the models for any Django question that involves querying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would like to thank Mayuresh, for his help**

Not sure why I got that error, but I found the solution with this:

```
private_galleries = models.Gallery.objects.filter(type = 1).filter(root_gallery__isnull = True).exclude(id__in = [x.gallery.id for x in user_galleries])
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Gallery.objects.filter(type = 2).filter(root_gallery__isnull = True).exclude(id__in = [x.id for x in request.user.usergallery_set()])
```

Should do it.

Comment: Ok, so this got me most of the way there, I ended up with 
`public_galleries = models.Gallery.objects.filter(type = 2).filter(root_gallery__isnull = True).exclude(id__in = [x.gallery.id for x in user_galleries])`

Answer (score 4):

This answer will not work for even moderately large numbers of `user_galleries`, since you're loading all of them into a list every time.

A better way is to use the QuerySet's [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method, which allows you to specify additional conditions in SQL for a `WHERE` clause.

From the Django docs:

> You can define explicit SQL WHERE clauses — perhaps to perform non-explicit joins — by using where. You can manually add tables to the SQL FROM clause by using tables.

In your case something like

```
private_galleries = Gallery.objects.filter(type=1, root_gallery__isnull=True) \
    .extra(where=['''
        yourapp_gallery.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM 
            ...long query used to generate user_galleries...  )
    '''])
```

would work. Unfortunately it means transcribing the query that produced `user_galleries` into SQL, so you need to decide whether the DRY/maintainability tradeoff is worth saving the overhead of loading that list into memory on every query. I suspect that with anything but a trivial number of `user_galleries` it is.

Note that there `where=` arg takes a *list* of strings.

More info in from the mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/koNQ7_BCeKw).